# How add 0 in front of every single digit of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, digits

Given a string such as

```
September 3  September 3  September 2  September 1 September 10 August 14
```

I want to have an output of

```
September 03  September 03  September 02  September 01 September 10 August 14
```

Tried some regular expressions with no luck :/

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried to solve it please?

Answer (score 2):

use this simple pattern

```
\b(\d)\b
```

and replace w/

```
0$1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/285)

```
#    \b(\d)\b
\b              # <word boundary>
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
\b              # <word boundary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding only numbers which are single digit ones. Then you can replace them with themselves preceded by zero. Your code can look like

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\d(?!\\d)", "0$0");
```

I used [lookaroud](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms `(?<!\\d)` `(?!\\d)` to make sure that digit we find `\d` has no other digits before or after.
Replacement `0$0` contains `0` literal and `$0` which is reference to group 0 - match found by our regex.

But if you are responsible for generating this text

```
September 3  September 3  September 2  September 1 September 10 August 14
```

from smaller parts `September 3`  `September 3`  `September 2`  `September 1` `September 10` `August 14` then maybe consider using [String formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to create this parts with this additional `0` like

```
String part = String.format("%s %02d","September",3);
System.out.println(part); //September 03
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below Snippet helps. This is a quick and dirty solution though :)

```
String currentDate = "September 3";
        String month = "", date = "";

        String tokens[] = currentDate.split(" ");
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(currentDate);
        int count = 0;
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if (count == 0) {
                month = st.nextToken();
                count++;
            } else if (count == 1) {
                date = st.nextToken();
                date = String.format("%2s", date).replace(' ', '0'); //Add zero before the string , if its not 2 digit
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Formatted Date is :- "
                + month.concat(" ").concat(date));
```